# Extract a prefix that is no longer than N characters and doesn't end with a specific character

Tags: shell

If I have a string that is a dash separated list of words

```
my-string-looks-like-this
```

I know that I can use `cut` to get the first 15 characters like this:

```
# str=my-string-looks-like-this
echo ${str} | cut -c-15
```

And that should return a string of length 15 `my-string-looks`

But what if, my string looked like this:

```
this-string-is-great
```

The last character of the substring would end up being a dash `this-string-is-`

Without knowing ahead of time what the string is, what can I add to or how can I change my command to drop any trailing dashes from the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way out is to just drop a trailing `-` should one result.

```
new_str=$(echo "$str" | cut -c-15)
new_str=${new_str%-}
```

Comment: This worked for me, and it's simple enough to understand. It also can be condensed to one line  `new_str=$(echo "$STR" | cut -c-15) && echo ${new_str%-}` or `&& result=${new_str%-}`